# Query Dynamic range List Name. Set lower limit range

Tags: spreadsheet

I have several ranges.

I need to address them through the upper and lower boundaries.

Tried different options for QUERY.

Nothing works.

Please help.

...
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:C'"&D4&"'......
...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I decided the question myself. Via INDIRECT**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).